# Cast webview android studio

Tags: android, webview, cast

Estou fazendo um app para meu site, que é só uma webview, alguém pode me dizer se é possível colocar para transmitir nas TV Smart? se sim, pode me indicar onde dar uma estudada sobre? ou até me ajudar por aqui mesmo, só tenho a WEBVIEW até agora.

Answer (score 1):

Recentemente eu estava dando suporte ao meu app de download de vídeos justamente ao suporte de cast, eu encontrei as seguintes opções:

**[Google cast SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/)**

Com ele você pode transmitir vídeo, áudio ou a dela de algum app ou jogo, ele está disponível para android, ios e chrome, está bem documentado mas para você aprender vai ter que se esforçar um pouco, dependendo do que você tem em mente você vai ter que registra esse app no console do google cast que custa 5 dólares, mas se não deseja customizar ui do receptor ou algo semelhante pode usar o player padrão que é de graça, creio que o google cast só da suporte a tvs com android a aparelhos do google cast como o Chromecast.

**[Samsung Smart View SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/smart-view)**

Este sdk visa televisores com o sistema operacional da Samsung, o Tizem. Mas o próprio site já recomenda que você use em conjunto com o google cast para um maior suporte, existe um guia de integração no site.